# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, java-7, noclassdeffounderror

I'm having a problem with building Java project with Flutter module when compiling it.
It shows the next problem:

`Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7`

I've changed gradle version in `ProjectName\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Change Java compiled version in `Project Structure` (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S) on windows in specific module, in my case it was `app` module

And change Gradle JDK in `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle` or (Ctrl + Alt + S) on windows